# Logtsash Ubuntu deployment issue

Tags: logstash

Team,

I installed Logstash 7.1.0 on Ubuntu 18.04. I am not entirely sure on how the pipelines work when Logstash is installed as a service. I can run the pipeline in the foreground, however, that's not good enough for Production.

I created a basic pipeline that takes data from a file and loads it to Elasticsearch. I can execute this pipeline easily using

```
/usr/share/logstash/> bin/logstash -f myfile.conf
```

All this while my logstash service is shutdown in the background so I can manually run the above command. The pipeline works fine and now I want to take this to Production.

I added the pipeline to `/etc/logstash/conf.d/myfile.conf` and restarted my logstash service. However, I do not see anything happening. Shouldn't logstash service on startup look at the files in the /etc/logstash/conf.d/ directory and execute all pipelines there? Is my understanding correct?

Thanks
Nick

Comment: What is your pipeline? Do you have any error in the log file? Share your pipeline config and the logs after you start logstash as a service.

Comment: The pipeline doesn't really matter. It could be as simple as read data from stdin{} and output it to stdout{}. The pipeline works perfectly fine when logstash is used as a foreground service. My question is a very generic one. Where does one put all their pipelines so that Logstash (background) can run them. Is it /etc/logstash/conf.d/*.conf?

Comment: The pipeline does matter in some cases, your example is one of them, if your pipeline have `stdin` as an input and you start logstash as a service, this pipeline will do nothing because nothing is being passed to the logstash process. The documentation is clear, you put your `.conf` files inside `/etc/logstash/conf.d/` or edit `pipelines.yml`, if your pipeline is not working, then it could be an error in the config, without seeing your config there is no way to say why it is not working. What does the logstash log says?

Answer (score 0):

You should update the `/usr/share/logstash/config/pipelines.yml` file to include your pipeline file, for example:

```
# This file is where you define your pipelines. You can define multiple.
# For more information on multiple pipelines, see the documentation:
#   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/multiple-pipelines.html

- pipeline.id: syslog
  path.config: "/usr/share/logstash/pipelines/syslog.conf"
- pipeline.id: nginx-access
  path.config: "/usr/share/logstash/pipelines/nginx-access.conf"
```

So it will run the pipelines once service start running.

See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/multiple-pipelines.html

Comment: In the docs it say that you should put pipelines there, but it never worked with me. I really don't know.

Comment: Weird. In pipelines.yml, there is already a folder (by default) added for pipelines. 
- pipeline.id: main
  path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/*.conf
Shouldn't logstash pick any conf file (pipeline) from this folder on startup?

Comment: Do you have multiple pipeline files there?

Comment: Not right now. Maybe in the future. Really confusing documentation. Cant believe a company like Elastic will leave things open ended like that.